# How to get name of tag from id in Django

Tags: python, django

I take list of medicines in "rlist"

```
rlist = []
#dName = disease name and r = resulted disease
rlist.append(Disease.objects.filter(dName = r).values_list('medicine',flat=True))
```

By running this statements, I have ids of taggable manager "medicine"

```
rlist =  [<QuerySet [7]>, <QuerySet [27, 28, 29, 30]>]
```

But, I want name of medicines instead of id.

How can I get that???

- models.py

  ```
  class TaggedMedicine(TaggedItemBase):
      content_object = models.ForeignKey("Disease")

      def __str__(self):
         return self.name

  class Disease(models.Model):
       did = models.AutoField(verbose_name='Disease Id', primary_key=True,auto_created=True)
       dName = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)

       symptoms = TaggableManager(verbose_name='symptoms list', through=TaggedSymptoms)                #tags with comma or space separated values
       symptoms.rel.related_name = "+"

       medicine = TaggableManager(verbose_name='medicine list',through=TaggedMedicine)
       medicine.rel.related_name = "+"
  ```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a representation. But if you want to change that representation, in your models.py, for Medicine class, override `__str__` method.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name #if you have a name attribute for it
```

Comment: because it doesn't have name attribute. It has content_object_id and tag_id.

Comment: this is for demonstration purpose, you can write any method/prop that self accepts. look the `__str__`  for the last model class. https://gist.github.com/marmeladze/b16976e91a792ce842f8695e402bdea5

Comment: I could not resolve this problem. I tried your suggestion. But, it also don't work for me.

Comment: as i see, there is no  `name` attribute defined for `TaggedMedicine` class. but you can try `self.disease.dName`.

Comment: I solved by correcting following statement.                                                                              **rlist.append(Disease.objects.filter(dName = r).values_list('medicine__name',flat=True)) **

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.